# Удаление строк из файла

Tags: python, файлы

У меня есть список элементов, которые нужно проверить на нахождение в файле. Я это пытаюсь сделать через этот код:

```
    with open(file = 'file.txt',mode = 'w') as file:
        for element in elements:
            element = str(element)
            for line in lines:
                if element not in line:
                    file.write(line)
```

Линии кода я получаю таким образом:

```
    with open(file = 'file.txt', mode = 'r') as read_lines:
        lines = read_lines.readlines()
```

Но к сожалению, это удаление строк не выполняет свою задачу. Как можно её решить?

Comment: Во-первых, `readlines` не обрезает `\n` в конце строк. Так что нужно учитывать это при сравнении. Во-вторых, если в вашем входном файле по одному элементу на строку, то второй `for` не нужен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно проверять наличие любого из элементов в каждой из строк (если я правильно понял задачу):

```
with open(file = 'file.txt',mode = 'w') as file:
    for line in lines:
        if not any(element in line for element in elements):
            file.write(line)
```

Comment: @MaxU Спасибо! Собственно, только ради этого и колбасился тут сегодня, надо уже делать перерыв )